# ctx.fillRect is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to code a rpg game but when I first start off my code it says `fillRect` is not a function. Now i have used `fillRect` many times but have never ran into this error. If you could please help me – this would be great!

**My code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ctx = null;
var tileW = 40,
    tileH = 40;
var mapW = 10,
    mapH = 10;
var currentSecond = 0,
    frameCount = 0,
    frameLastSecond = 0;

var gameMap =
[
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
];

window.onload = function ()
{
    ctx = document.getElementById('game');
    requestAnimationFrame(drawGame);
    ctx.font = "bold 18pt sans-serif";
};

function drawGame ()
{
    if(ctx == null){return;}

    var sec = Math.floor(Date.now()/ 1000);
    if(sec!= currentSecond)
    {
        currentSecond = sec;
        frameLastSecond = frameCount;
        frameCount = 1;
    }
    else { frameCount++;}

    for(var y = 0; y < mapH; y++)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x < mapW; x++)
        {
            switch(gameMap[((y*mapW)+x)])
            {
                case 0:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#999999";
                    break;
                default:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#eeeeee";
            }
            ctx.fill(x*tileW, y*tileH, tileW, tileH);
        }
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
    ctx.fillText("FPS:  " + frameLastSecond, 10, 20);

    requestAnimationFrame(drawGame);
}
</script>
</head><body>
<canvas id="game" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body></html>
```

Again I have yet to find a solution to this. So if anyone in this community can help me – this would be great.

Comment: Your ctx is the canvas element not the canva's rendering context object, eg [CanvasRenderingContext2d](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D)

Comment: your missing to call `getContext` method. Try `ctx.getContext('2d');` after referencing the `#game`canvas.

Comment: There is just no `fillRect` in this code, it's thus impossible that you got the error you said you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your code:

1. instead of `ctx = document.getElementById('game');` you have to write `var canvas = document.getElementById('game'); ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');` or `ctx = document.getElementById('game').getContext('2d');`
2. instead of `ctx.fill(x * tileW, y * tileH, tileW, tileH);` you have to write `ctx.fillRect(x * tileW, y * tileH, tileW, tileH);`

I corrected it for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ctx = null,
    tileW = 40,
    tileH = 40,
    mapW = 10,
    mapH = 10,
    currentSecond = 0,
    frameCount = 0,                                                                               
    frameLastSecond = 0;

var gameMap =
[
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
     0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
     0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
     0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
     0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
     0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
     0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
];

window.onload = function()
{
     // here was the first mistake:
     ctx = document.getElementById('game').getContext('2d');
     requestAnimationFrame(drawGame);
     ctx.font = "bold 18pt sans-serif";
};

function drawGame()
{
     if (ctx == null) {return;}

     var sec = Math.floor(Date.now()/ 1000);
     if(sec!= currentSecond)
     {
          currentSecond = sec;
          frameLastSecond = frameCount;
          frameCount = 1;

     }
     else
     {
          frameCount++;
     }

     for(var y = 0; y < mapH; y++)
     {
          for(var x = 0; x < mapW; x++)
          {
               switch(gameMap[((y*mapW)+x)])
               {
                    case 0:
                         ctx.fillStyle = "#999999";
                         break;

                    default:
                         ctx.fillStyle = "#eeeeee";
               }

               // here was the second mistake:
               ctx.fillRect(x * tileW, y * tileH, tileW, tileH);
          }
     }
     ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000"
     ctx.fillText("FPS:  " + frameLastSecond, 10, 20);

     requestAnimationFrame(drawGame);
}
</script>
</head><body>
<canvas id="game" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body></html>
```